# How to update the $scope manually in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

After i have updated a user in angularjs I will update the $scope.user with the new userdata. One way is to do an new api request to get all users. But i think, its better to update the $scope. I found $apply, but i'am not sure how to use it.

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', function( $scope, APIService )  {

    $scope.users = APIService.query({ route:'users' });

    $scope.activate = function( user ) {

        var updateUser = {};

        if(user.activated) {

            updateUser.activated = false;

        } else {

            updateUser.activated = true;

        }

        APIService.update({ route:'users', id: user._id }, updateUser, function(updatedUser) {


            //update $scope.users with new data from updatedUser;

        });

    }

});
```

The updatedUser looks like this:

```
{"__v":0,"_id":"535aa89d8b2766d012e14c21","activated":true,"role":"user","local":{"surname":"Carter","prename":"Rob","password":"459DS","email":"test"},"$promise":{},"$resolved":true}
```

the service:

```
app.service("APIService", function( $resource ) {

    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/:route/:id', { route: "@route", id: "@id" }, {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' }
    });

});
```

Comment: Can we see the service code for the `update` method? It would seem that you're giving the method a callback instead of AngularJS's `.then()` with a promise.

Comment: sure, i updated my first post. In another project i use: angular.copy(updatedUser, $scope.users[index]); Do you think thats an option?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ngRoute` use:

`$route.reload()`

```
Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.

As a result of that, ngView creates new scope, reinstantiates the controller.
```

and if you're using `ui-router`:

`$state.reload();`

However I think a better way would be to recall the $resource call again:

```
var getUsers=function(){
    $scope.users = APIService.query({ route:'users' });
}
```

You can call it initially like this:

`getUsers();`

and in the callback of your update:

```
APIService.update({ route:'users', id: user._id }, updateUser, function(updatedUser) {
   getUsers();
});
```

EDIT

I'm not sure what you mean by "updating the scope"? You mean rerunning the controller again? In that case you're making a fresh API call again, the same thing as just calling the `getUsers()` method I suggested. If you mean you want to update an array that sits on your `$scope` with the new data of the user, rather than calling the server to get the entire users again, then in the callback of your update method do something like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.users,function(user,key){
  if(user._id == updatedUser._id){
    $scope.users[key]=updatedUser;
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you! Thats what I mean with my api request. But maybe there is a better way to update the scope instead of request the entire user-data.